# can we select only modified bones from a pose in the library?

Tags: bones, pose-mode

When applying a pose from the library, I have to:

1 - spend some time to grant there is no bones already selected
1.1 - but I usually hit 'A' until it selects all and then hit 'A' again to deselect all (instead of reading on the status bar at the top how many stuff is selected)
1.1.1 - but that only works if I have at least one bone selected otherwise it will select something else and I have to aim for any bone before doing *1.1 again (yes, it is usually: again)
2 - navigate to bone groups and click on a bone group
3 - click on select, to have selected only the bones I want to collect from the pose library entry.
4 - click on that button that applies it on selected bones only

I wonder, if there is some way to let that pose library entry affect ONLY the bones that were modified relatively to the rest pose (the first on the list, also the one used at "apply as rest pose").

So, I wonder if there is some way to SELECT ONLY such modified bones from the pose library entry, prior to applying that pose from the library?
The best thing would still be some single-click/hotkey to: "select and apply only modified bones from this lib's pose's entry"

Obs.:
learned from here: https://blenderartists.org/t/not-all-bones-saved-in-pose-library/1132846/4

Comment: I don't know if you can but you could use the Bone Groups to be sure to only select the group of bones you want to select for your pose

Comment: I've been doing that, but it is too many clicks and attention for something that could be more intuitive :)

Comment: yes, I once wondered and I agree with you

Comment: I guess this will probably fit better as a suggestion at blender's forum? but I still hope there is some scripted tool that could do that if not builtin already somewhere I am missing.

Comment: I hope the gods of Blender will hear you  :))